# couchbase query workbench connection to https://couchbase:18091

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to connect to my couchbase instance using query workbench on 18091 ( https ) and not able to connect . 
HTTP 8091 works without any issues. We are trying to limit couchbase access to SSL only . 
Am I missing some parameter to pass to cqb-gui ?

Comment: cbq-gui is a developer preview. I'm not sure it has the security features.
You should try using the Couchbase 4.5 dp which comes with the query gui built in.

Comment: Yes, we just updated to 4.5dev preview on our test setup. 
Thanks for your response.

Comment: So is it working with 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the cbq-gui developer preview. As a developer preview, it's missing a number of features, and support for HTTPS is one of them. (That's actually a limitation in the underlying go-couchbase library which it uses. We can hope it will be fixed one of these days.)

Roi Katz is correct that Couchbase 4.5 has the Query Workbench built-in, so if you can use 4.5 that is your best option. In addition, the Query Workbench in version 4.5 has a number of improvements and new features w.r.t. the developer preview, and should continue to be improved moving forward.